# upload a mp4 video with php to a server

Tags: php, linux

i´m working with a multimedia router, which has a Linaro Linux distribution. It has a web portal to allow the clients to surf throug offline content. I´m in charge in the development maintenance page. I´m trying to do a page wich allow to upload a video file, but after 30 secs the transfer stop and appear an error.

I have read that changing elements in php.ini the problem disappear, but it dnt happen...what can i do?

i´m trying with phpseclib, if i install the phpseclib in my eclipse-apache and try to comunicate with the router sending the file is ok, but when i put the php file in the router and execute it, it dnt work, it stop when it has passed 5 minutes....

thank you :)

Comment: Have you realized this is a Spanish site?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no está en español

Comment: So some code, which we can't see, throws an error, which you haven't shared with us. That doesn't give us a whole lot to go on.